# Mozilla Firefox scrollbar click creates a border in that link

Tags: jquery, html, css, mozilla

1. I have a  tag and inside the  tag i have  and

   tag. when i'm using scrollbar click to open the link in new tab means it creates the border in Mozilla Firefox.
2. Then i'm clicking anywhere in the window means it went automatically.

This is my code:

```
<div class="blockquote-box  blockquote-warning clearfix">
<div class="square pull-left">
    <img style="width:40px" src="//az177188.vo.msecnd.net/static/planobot/images/services-2.png" alt /> <span class="fa fa-heart fav-link" style="font-size: 18px;" title="Add to My Favourites"></span>

</div> <a href="/reports/monthlysnapshotreport">
                                <h4>
                                    Monthly Snapshot Report
                                </h4>
                                <p>
                                    Monthly summary of revenue breakup, customer statistics and cashbook.
                                </p>
                            </a>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you mean the default dotted border for `:active` link (`border: outline` which is there do to accessibilty)? If no, please add JSFiddle to your problem including CSS. If so, where is the problem exactly?

Comment: Panther ... Image url: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkybx.png

Comment: This problem exists only in Firefox. . . when i'm clicking that link in scrollbar click

Comment: `a:active {outline: none}`. If not, add JSFiddle link incl. CSS.

Comment: @Panther.. the Problem is fixed.. the border exists in the <a> focus... a:focus{outline:none}

Comment: Sure, there should be `a:focus`, not `a:active`. My fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a:focus{outline:none} to Remove the border After selection it through scrollbar click..